# How to start click-once application .application file on UNC path with Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: clickonce, windows-task-scheduler, unc

I've found quite a few posts on the net describing a similar or even the same situation but there were almost no replies and none that helped me get this working.

The setup is rather simple. I have a .net application that is published to a UNC network path. On a specific workstation this app is installed from this path. Using Windows Task Scheduler it is supposed to be started every hour at a specific time.

The program gets started as intended when I identify the install location in ...\AppData\Local\Apps... and put the path to the .exe file in the task scheduler program/script field.
However, I'd like to reference the .application file in the publish folder on the network in the task action to pick up and install updates as they are available. **This is the point I ask for help** since when I do so nothing happens at all when the trigger fires.

As workaround I created a PowerShell script `"Start-Process -FilePath "*projectname*.application" -WorkingDirectory "\\*UNC-Path*"` and put the path to it in the argument field in the task scheduler action and *powershell.exe* in program/script field. Same behavior, the script starts but the .application file is not called. Even with transcript turned on, no error is recorded, it fails silently with no warning whatsoever. When I execute the script manually it works fine!

Is this rather an issue of task scheduler and network drive or task scheduler and .application file I don't know what to check and try further. Anyone?